# Define custom casting of RealProxy

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

Is it possible to define custom casting behavior of a transparent proxy in the real proxy class?
Example:

```
public class TestProxy : RealProxy
{
    public TestProxy() : base(typeof(MarshalByRefObject))
    {

    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```
object proxy = new TestProxy().GetTransparentProxy();
Console.WriteLine((string)proxy);
```

This code throws *System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast transparent proxy to type System.String.* Is it possible to detect the cast and process it in the `TestProxy` class?

Edit: Code to cast to a COM interface would suffice.

Comment: I don't think so. Intercepting cast(using explicit operator) is a compile time feature. Your cast is trying to cast from `object` to `string`. So even if you implement some `explicit` conversion operator, it won't work as `proxy` is typed as `object`. C# compiler needs to know the type information at compile time.

Comment: @Sriram I disagree. Casting from `object` to any other type is done by the CLR, and as you can see, the CLR handles this by throwing a very specific exception.

Comment: I know; maybe I worded it wrong, I'm talking about how to intercept the calls. You can implement `explicit` operator to intercept it, but c# compiler needs the static type information to make it work. I amended my last comment to make sense.

Comment: @Sriram Of course, but that's not what I am asking for. It seems logical to me that if you can intercept even the `GetType` call, there should also be a way to intercept the cast, as it is (more or less) the same thing. Edit: The point was it should work with any type, not just some user defined type of mine.

Comment: You can't intercept `GetType`. Can you explain how you do?

Comment: @Sriram Just change the last line of my example code to `Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetType());`. It will throw that `NotImplementedException` from the `Invoke` method. If I fully implemented the method, I would be able to return anything I want (of `Type`, of course).

Comment: Are you looking for [`IRemotingTypeInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.iremotingtypeinfo.aspx) by any chance (you can implement that interface in your proxy)?

Comment: @Lucas That interface doesn't seem to solve the problem. There is a method to check for a cast possible, but not a method for the actual cast.

Comment: @IllidanS4 with transparent proxies, there is no actual cast. The proxy intercepts all the calls. If `CanCastTo` returns `true`, it means your proxy should intercept the calls. If it returns `false`, it means the cast should fail. But I doubt you'll be able to cast to `string` anyway, IIRC it must be an interface or a `MarshalByRef`-derived object.

Comment: @Lucas I understand now. The result object will be the same, but it will allow to handle the calls on the interface or marshalbyref class. This suffices, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've ever been able to accomplish this is by using Castle in addition to vanilla .NET code. I've never found the public methods and properties on the .NET objects themselves robust enough to accomplish my needs.

I've generally dealt with this by using the Castle Windsor WCF Facility, which does mean you have to use Castle Windsor for your DI (or have 2 containers).

You can also use Castle.DynamicProxy by itself, as detailed here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx